# Bootstrap modal not sending a request to django view for rendering model form

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently working on a django project that manages inventory of biological samples. I have a specimen details page that renders four tables with data associated with the selected specimen. In each of these tables I have an Edit button where the user can update a record associated with the specimen. Right now, when the button is clicked, a new page is opened and the update form is rendered. I'd like to use a bootstrap modal to create a popup of the form instead of having to go to a whole new page. I already created something similar on the home page for adding a new specimen record and it works great. For some reason tryin the same thing on the details page will not work. The modal does pop up, but the form does not render and it seems like the issue is that there is no request being sent to the edit_specimen url/view even though it is specified. Im wondering if it has to do with urls and the pk being in the url for this operation. I've tried several things and I can't get it to work. Any advice is appreciated as I am relatively new to Django.

Here is the html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the view

```
def EditSpecimenView(request,pk):
    instance = Specimen.objects.get(specimen_id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        specimen_update_form = UpdateSpecimenForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if specimen_update_form.is_valid:
            specimen_update_form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            specimen_update_form = UpdateSpecimenForm()
    else:
        specimen_update_form = UpdateSpecimenForm()
    context = {'spec_form': specimen_update_form}

    return render(request, 'zombie/edit_specimen.html', context)

Here are my urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('zombie/edit-specimen/(?P<pk>\w+)/', views.EditSpecimenView, name='edit_specimen'),
    path('zombie/edit-sample', views.EditSampleView, name='edit_sample'),
    path('zombie/edit-morphometrics', views.EditMorphsView, name='edit_morphometrics'),
    path('zombie/load-species/', views.get_species, name='get_species'),
    path("zombie/add-specimen/", views.AddSpecimenView, name='add_specimen'),
    path("zombie/specimen-details/(?P<pk>\w+)/", views.SpecimenDetailView, name='details'),
    path("search-results/", views.SearchResultsView, name='specimen_search_results'),
    path("home/", views.HomeTableView, name="home"),
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

I've tried different suggestions for implementing the modal and taking the modal from the home page and placing it into this page and it still doesn't render which makes me think it has to do with the url/pk

EDIT:
adding html and views for home table/search page. I probably need to combine into one view but will work on that later.

```
    #home.html
        {% load django_tables2  %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <style>
        /* Center the logo horizontally */
        .center-logo {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            transform: scale(0.8);
        }
    
        .tooltip-icon {
        font-size: 12px; /* Adjust the size of the "i" icon */
        color: coral;
        }
    
        .tooltip-icon:hover {
        font-size: 12px; /* Increase size on hover if desired */
    }
    
    </style>
    
    <head>
        <title>Specimen Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                {% load static %}
                <img src="{% static 'zombie/logo.png' %}" alt="Your Image" class="center-logo">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <form action="{% url 'specimen_search_results' %}" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                    {{ forms.toggle }}&nbsp&nbsp{{ forms.search_bar }}
                    &nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSpecimenModal"
                        style="float: right;">
                        Add Specimen Record
                    </button>
                        {% block content %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  Hi {{ user.username }}!
                  <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></p>
                {% else %}
                  <p>You are not logged in</p>
                  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
                </form>
    
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="addSpecimenModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSpecimenModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addSpecimenModalLabel">Add Specimen Record</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                               <form method="post" id="specimenForm" data-species-url="{% url 'get_species' %}" novalidate>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <table>
                                    {% for field in spec_form %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
    
                                        <td>
                                            {% if field.label == 'spec_id' %}
                                                {{ field }}
                                                <button type="button" class="tooltip-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ field.help_text }}">i</button>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ field }}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </table>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="specimenForm">Add Record</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Display the Table -->
                {% if table %}
                {% render_table table %}
                {% else %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
    
            <!-- Include Bootstrap JS and jQuery -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        // Event handler for the class dropdown.
        $("#id_tclass").change(function () {
            var url = $("#specimenForm").attr('data-species-url');
            var classID = $(this).val();
            var selectedField = 'class';
    
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'id': classID,
                    'selected_field': selectedField,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_order").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    
        // Event handler for the order dropdown.
        $("#id_order").change(function () {
            var url = $("#specimenForm").attr('data-species-url');
            var orderID = $(this).val();
            var selectedField = 'order';
    
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'id': orderID,
                    'selected_field': selectedField,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_family").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    
        // Event handler for the family dropdown.
        $("#id_family").change(function () {
            var url = $("#specimenForm").attr('data-species-url');
            var familyID = $(this).val();
            var selectedField = 'family';
    
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'id': familyID,
                    'selected_field': selectedField,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_genus").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    
        // Event handler for the genus dropdown.
        $("#id_genus").change(function () {
            var url = $("#specimenForm").attr('data-species-url');
            var genusID = $(this).val();
            var selectedField = 'genus';
    
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'id': genusID,
                    'selected_field': selectedField,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_species").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#home').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    #search_results.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Specimen Table</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <style>
        .center-logo {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            transform: scale(0.8);
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                {% load static %}
                <img src="{% static 'zombie/logo.png' %}" alt="Your Image" class="center-logo">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <form action="{% url 'specimen_search_results' %}" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                    {{ forms.toggle }}&nbsp&nbsp{{ forms.search_bar }}
                    &nbsp;<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSpecimenModal"
                        style="float: right;">
                        Add Specimen Record
                    </button>
                </form>
    
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="addSpecimenModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSpecimenModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addSpecimenModalLabel">Add Specimen Record</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                               <form method="post" id="specimenForm" data-species-url="{% url 'get_species' %}" novalidate>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <table>
                                    {% for field in spec_form %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
    
                                        <td>
                                            {% if field.label == 'spec_id' %}
                                                {{ field }}
                                                <button type="button" class="tooltip-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ field.help_text }}">i</button>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{ field }}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </table>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="specimenForm">Add Record</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            {% if table %}
                {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
                {% render_table table %}
            {% else %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#home').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here are the views

```
@login_required
def HomeTableView(request):
    from zombie.models import Master_Table
    forms = SpecimenSearchForm()
    queryset = Master_Table.objects.all()
    table = HomeTable(queryset)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        spec_form = SpecimenForm(request.POST)
        if spec_form.is_valid():
            try:
                new_specimen = spec_form.save()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        spec_form = SpecimenForm()

    return render(request, 'zombie/home.html',
                  {'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1)), 'forms': forms, 'spec_form': spec_form})

@login_required
def SearchResultsView(request):
    from zombie.models import Master_Table
    forms = SpecimenSearchForm()
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    value = request.GET.get('search_bar')
    param = request.GET.get('toggle')
    if param =='t':
        print(value)
        tax = Master_Table.objects.filter(
            Q(t_class=value) |
            Q(torder=value) |
            Q(family=value) |
            Q(genus=value) |
            Q(species__icontains=value)
        )
        print(tax)
        table = HomeTable(tax)
        context = {
                'forms': forms,
                'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1))
            }
        return render(request, 'zombie/search_results.html', context)


    elif param=='s':
        query = Master_Table.objects.filter(id__icontains=value)
        print(query)
        table = HomeTable(query)
        context = {
            'forms': forms,
            'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1))
        }
        return render(request, 'zombie/search_results.html', context)

    elif param == 'c':
        query = Master_Table.objects.filter(common_name__icontains=value)
        table=HomeTable(query)
        context = {
            'forms': forms,
            'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1))
        }
        return render(request, 'zombie/search_results.html', context)
    elif param == 'cl':
        query = Master_Table.objects.filter(collector__icontains=value)
        table = HomeTable(query)
        context = {
            'forms': forms,
            'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1))
        }
        return render(request, 'zombie/search_results.html', context)
    elif param=='type':
        sample_query = Sample.objects.values_list('specimen_id').filter(sample_type=value)
        sample_query = list(sample_query)
        specimen_ids = []
        for id in sample_query:
            if len(id) > 0:
                specimen_ids.append(id[0].split("'")[0])
        specimen_query = Master_Table.objects.filter(id__in = specimen_ids)
        table = HomeTable(specimen_query)
        context = {
            'forms': forms,
            'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1))
        }

        return render(request, 'zombie/home.html', {'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1)), 'forms': forms})
    elif param=='status':
        sample_query = Sample.objects.values_list('specimen_id').filter(status=value)
        sample_query = list(sample_query)
        specimen_ids = []
        for id in sample_query:
            if len(id) > 0:
                specimen_ids.append(id[0].split("'")[0])
        specimen_query = Master_Table.objects.filter(id__in=specimen_ids)
        table = HomeTable(specimen_query)
        context = {
            'forms': forms,
            'table': table.paginate()
        }

        return render(request, 'zombie/home.html', {'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1)), 'forms': forms})
    else:
        queryset = Master_Table.objects.all()
        table = HomeTable(queryset)
        return render(request, 'zombie/home.html', {'table': table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1)), 'forms': forms, })
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup of the `EditSpecimenView` view, making a get request to the view will return an empty form as you are not passing in the model instance of the specimen.

Try this.

```
def EditSpecimenView(request,pk):
    instance = Specimen.objects.get(specimen_id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        specimen_update_form = UpdateSpecimenForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if specimen_update_form.is_valid:
            specimen_update_form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        specimen_update_form = UpdateSpecimenForm(instance=instance)

    context = {'spec_form': specimen_update_form}

    return render(request, 'zombie/edit_record.html', context)
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but it still isn't rendering the form. The popup comes up but with no form. And it seems like no request is being sent to the view because if I print the request nothing shows up when I click the edit button.

Comment: can you show the html template and view responsible for showing the list of specimens before you get into the specimen detail view

Comment: I just added them up above. Thanks

Comment: Also, the problem is that it isn't rendering the form at all. So the popup comes up but with no form or input fields at all